# Redeclaring a class (in a lower directory)

Tags: php

I have the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Database in /home/content/63/8026363/html/include/user_database.php on line 5

That links to the line

> class Database

But I have not redeclared this anywhere I can see.

I've checked all the include files and still can't see it.

I have now changed the name to user_database1.php which is DEFINITELY only included once in my WHOLE system and I am still getting the same message!

This only occurs in my root/admin directory. 
When I moved the file it occurs into the root directory and updated the include files from ../file.php to just file.php, it worked perfectly.

I can't understand why having the file.php in the /admin directory and using ../ to include files isn't working!

Can anyone offer any experience of this? Or a potential fix.

I'll provide some code from the top of the file in question..

```
<?php

include("../include/session.php");
include("../include/admin_database.php");
```

Clearly this is the problem but I can't understand why!

Hope someone can help !

(question has been updated significantly since a lot of the answers below were submitted)

Comment: With a name so generic, I wouldn't be surprised if one of the many extensions has a class called `Database`.  Are you sure you searched all the files in your application as well?

Comment: Perhaps you are using require instead of require_once in a file that is referencing /home/content/63/8026363/html/include/user_database.php?

Comment: I have now changed the name to user_database1.php which is DEFINITELY only included once in my WHOLE system and I am still getting the same message!

Answer (score 3):

If you included the file two times, theen it gets re-declared. Use `include_once()` instead to prevent that easily.

If you are unsure where that class was originally declared, you can make use of the [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to get the name of the file and the line of code:

```
$class = 'Database';
if(class_exists($class))
{
  $oRefl = new ReflectionClass($class);
  $message = sprintf('Class %s already defined in %s on line %s.', $class, $oRefl->getFileName, $oRefl->getStartLine);
  throw new DomainException($message);
}
```

Place that before the line where you define the class `Database` to find out which file was originally defining the class.

Comment: Got this when running that Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'Class Database was already defined in on line .' in /home/content/63/8026363/html/index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: Check you `index.php` file at line 9. Is there a `class Database` probably?

Comment: No there isn't. What I have noticed is that the script causing problems is one directory lower, so I use a ../ to get back to the main directory. When i moved the script up a directory and changed the links, it was perfect. Any ideas?

Comment: What? You get the exception based on the reflection data, but there is no definition at all? You must be cheating. Please post line 9 and 10 lines around of index.php or from which file your right now get messaged and add it to your question.

Comment: Please add the next 10 lines as well to it. Sorry but this does not make really sense, but there must be a class definition somewhere.

Comment: Don't apologise, if you can help fix this, I'll be very grateful. Please note the problem happens in a script admin/admin.php, whereas this code is from index.php in the root directory. I can't get admin.php to run at all, so used a different file. ANYTHING that is in the admin directory won't run. But when I moved the admin.php down to the root directory and changed the include files from ../ to nothing, it worked. Hmmmmmm!

Answer (score 1):

Check if php already defines a file called Database.php.
Maybe you are using some framework or library which does.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he means `does`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have included your database class more than once, a quick fix for this is to add something like this to the top of your class:

```
if(!class_exists('Database')){
    class Database{
    // so on
}
```

This ensures that your class is only defined once.

Comment: i added that code and got this Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19456 bytes)

Comment: Looks like your host is limiting you to 64 megabytes of memory. You may have some performance issues in your code that need to be addressed.

Comment: It just randomly happened though, was fine earlier. Then I tried to run the script again and it stopped working!